# How to add label into d3 node

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to draw a force directed graph in d3 version4. 
I have nodes, lines and labels for the nodes, but I can't seem to add the labels right next to the nodes.

All of the labels are placed in one place (at top of the svg canvas).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
.node {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.link {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
</style>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<body>
  <p>Hello</p>
</body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-200))
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }).distance(40))
    .force("x", d3.forceX(width / 2))
    .force("y", d3.forceY(height / 2));

var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
    node = svg.selectAll(".node"),
    label = svg.selectAll("text");

d3.json("graph.json", function(error, graph) {
  if (error) throw error;

  link = link
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link");

  //Here are the nodes
  node = node
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 6)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d.id; });

  //Here is the label that I want to add to each node
  label = label
    .data(graph.nodes)
      .enter().append("text")
      .text(function(d) { return d.id; })
      .attr('dx', "0.35em")
      .attr('dy', "0.35em");

  simulation.nodes(graph.nodes);
  simulation.force("link").links(graph.links);

});
</script>
```

And my graph.json file looks like:

```js
{
  "nodes": [
    {"id": "Shift Leader", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Dispatcher", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Mechanics", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Drilling", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Blasting", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Loading", "group": 3}
  ],
  "links": [
    {"source": "Shift Leader", "target": "Dispatcher"},
    {"source": "Shift Leader", "target": "Drilling"},
    {"source": "Shift Leader", "target": "Dispatcher"},
    {"source": "Blasting", "target": "Dispatcher"},
    {"source": "Drilling", "target": "Dispatcher"}
  ]
}
```

There are no error messages, but the label isn't placed in the right place

Comment: Where is your tick function? (the function you use to position the circles and lines)

Comment: Well, S.O. is a quite active community: when asking a question it's a good idea sticking around for some 5 minutes, just to check the comments.

Comment: Why <svg> is placed outside the <body>?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Oh I deleted the "tick" function because it was irrelevant to my question,

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky uh, it was there in the previous code I referred to, but had the same result anyways either it is inside or outside the body,

Comment: @SoHeumHwang Irellevant? Why do you think so? It's the **main** thing for answering your question.